Play DVD through VLC in Dolphin / Mimetype of DVD?
I like to watch DVDs on my computer, I am using KDE Plasma 6.1.3. There is no option to play the DVD through VLC Media Player or something of the sorts. I didnt find a way to add this option through regular means, like installing a package, I already got kio-fuse, kio-extras, dolphin-plugins etc.
https://develop.kde.org/docs/apps/dolphin/service-menus/
I found this through my searches, adding my own service menu seemed like a fair option. Though I could not find the Mime Type for DVDs; on this list (https://www.digipres.org/formats/mime-types/) I found video/dvd but it doesnt do the trick, the menu doesnt show.
I also tried applying it to directories, thinking I might get recognized as directory, but it didnt work.
Any idea would I could do?
Thanks



https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs 2. You can always open the DVD directly from within VLC (File - Open disk...). What is the question exactly?


I know I can open it from VLC. I used GNOME before and in Nautilus, you could right click DVDs and let it play directly from the file managers context menu. Windows has this too (play with Windows Media Player). I just thought KDE might have something like this too?

Make sure you have libdvdcss2 installed. libdvd-pkg_1.4.3-1-1_all.deb Should play in any player after that.
